# How to upgrade Ubuntu using Live DVD?

Tags: upgrade, 14.04

I have a very slow internet connection (200kbps), and don't want to wait for it to install all packages from the web. Is it possible to upgrade to 14.04 from 12.04 using the Live DVD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But of course. In theory it is possible to upgrade Ubuntu from any version to any (newer) version.

However, it may not work due to dependencies. Every single upgrade goes ahead and breaks an entire package chain.

Go head with it, just make sure you back up.

---

Just note that the easiest way to do an upgrade would be the wonderful clean install.

Comment: Your reply was the most useful of all :)

Answer (score 2):

First go and download and burn Ubuntu ISO image onto a CD/DVD disc. 
Then take the disc to your Ubuntu PC and boot from it.
Next, click ‘Install Ubuntu’
Then click ‘Continue’  Since your Internet connection is not reliable, you probably don’t want to download updates while upgrading Ubuntu. It may just add more delays to the process.
Next, choose the 2nd option shown below (Upgrade Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) and click ‘Install Now’
Make sure to use the same username and password you’re currently using on this screen and click ‘Continue’
Wait for the upgrade to complete and click ‘Restart Now’ when you see the screenshot shown.
That’s it! All your documents and folders should stay intact after upgrading.

Enjoy!

Comment: I can't download it because my internet is too slow...

Comment: You can get a free DVD from Canonical. Go to a library and search for how to get the DVD.