# Is it possible to upgrade from Xubuntu 14.04 LTS to Xubuntu 16.04 LTS via USB?

Tags: 14.04, usb, xubuntu, 16.04, lts

An USB upgrade is the only way I can do it. That's not my computer, his connection is very slow and it would take ages to download it.

I had installed the **Xubuntu** 14.04 LTS via USB, now I'd like to upgrade it with the new 16.04 LTS. Some suggest to do a clean install, some say it's okay to upgrade from a LTS to another one.
Could you help me? What file do I need if I can upgrade via USB?
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 using a live DVD. You need to burn the live DVD of the same flavor (e.g. Xubuntu) and run the installer. If it detects the previous LTS version, it will prompt you to upgrade.

See this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/475494/271

However, keep in mind that the package installation phase in this mode is (in my experience) **very slow.** You might still consider performing an upgrade using the network, esplicitly asking for all possible releases:

```
sudo update-manager -c
```

Answer (score 0):

14.04 --> 16.4 is not a supported upgrade path.

You'll be able to upgrade once 16.04.**1** comes out.

Comment: @guntbert - Sorry, **you** are wrong. The supported upgrade path is 14.04 --> 16.04 **.1**

Comment: The question asks if it is possible to upgrade, not if this is "supported" (whatever that means) or recommended. It is possible to upgrade from LTS to LTS hence this does answer the question.

Comment: @AndroidDev, I concede that it is clearly too early for a LTS->LTS upgrade (and I should have said it less harsh - apologies). What remains is the contradiction about an offline upgrade - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes?_ga=1.243272837.1440713220.1462450521#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_or_15.10 says "no offline upgrades".

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Release Notes for Xenial Xerus](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes?_ga=1.243272837.1440713220.1462450521#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_or_15.10) the LTS->LTS upgrade will get enabled with the so called *1st point release* (16.04.1) due some time during summer.

But also according to the same release notes

> There are no offline upgrade options for Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server. Please ensure you have network connectivity to one of the official mirrors or to a locally accessible mirror and follow the instructions above.

So there will be no official way to upgrade directly.