# Stick or Disk to upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: upgrade

Is there a stick or disk that I can buy to upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04?

Comment: Maybe you can buy it from https://www.osdisc.com/ (depending on where you live).

Comment: You don't need a USB or DVD to **UPGRADE** 16.04 to 18.04. You need it for a **NEW INSTALL** of 18.04.  Ignore the duplicate question and answers for new installs. You simply need to type `sudo do-release-upgrade` at the command line. You can upgrade via USB/DVD after 18.04.1 comes out as per this answer about 14.04 to 16.04.1 upgrades via USB/DVD: https://askubuntu.com/questions/766373/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-from-xubuntu-14-04-lts-to-xubuntu-16-04-lts-via-usb

Comment: **Reopen Voters** OP's question is about UPGRADING, duplicate close target is about NEW INSTALLS.

Comment: Voting to leave closed as a shopping recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Some magazines (Example Linux Format) include DVD that can be used.

https://shop.ubuntu.com/ do not have USB sticks any more.